# Error in parsing json Expecting '{', '['**

Tags: json, jsonlint

This is the json .

```
"{
    'places': [
        {
            'name': 'New\x20Orleans,
            \x20US\x20\x28New\x20Lakefront\x20\x2D\x20NEW\x29',
            'code': 'NEW'
        }

    ]
}"
```

I am getting json parsererror. I am checking on http://jsonlint.com/ and it shows following error

```
Parse error on line 1:
"{    'places': [ 
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

Please explain what are the problems with the json and do I correct it?

Comment: You are using a string, not json...

Comment: In previous versions of the JSON standard a String alone is not a valid JSON document. It must be an object or an array.

Answer (score 5):

If you literally mean that the string, as a whole, is your JSON text (containing something that isn't JSON), there are three issues:

1. It's just a JSON *fragment*, not a full JSON document.
2. Literal line breaks within strings are not valid in JSON, use `\n`.
3. `\x` is an invalid escape sequence in JSON strings. If you want your contained non-JSON text to have a `\x` escape (e.g., when you read the value of the overall string and parse it), you have to escape that backslash: `\\x`.

In a full JSON document, the top level must be an object or array:

```
{"prop": "value"}

[1, 2, 3]
```

Most JSON parsers support parsing *fragments*, such as standalone strings. (For instance, JavaScript's `JSON.parse` supports this.) http://jsonlint.com is doing full document parsing, however.

Here's your fragment wrapped in an object with the line breaks and `\x` issue handled:

```
{
    "stuff": "{\n 'places': [\n {\n 'name': 'New\\x20Orleans,\n \\x20US\\x20\\x28New\\x20Lakefront\\x20\\x2D\\x20NEW\\x29',\n 'code': 'NEW'\n }\n \n ]\n }"
}
```

---

The text *within* the string is also not valid JSON, but perhaps it's not meant to be. For completeness: JSON requires that all keys and strings be in **double** quotes (`"`), not single quotes (`'`). It also doesn't allow literal line breaks within string literals (use `\n` instead), and doesn't support `\x` escapes. See http://json.org for details.

Here's a version as valid JSON with the `\x` converted to the correct JSON `\u` escape:

```
{
    "places": [
        {
            "name": "New\u0020Orleans,\n\u0020US\u0020\u0028New\u0020Lakefront\u0020\u002D\u0020NEW\u0029",
            "code": "NEW"
        }
    ]
}
```

...also those escapes are all actually defining perfectly normal characters, so:

```
{
    "places": [
        {
            "name": "New Orleans,\n US (New Lakefront - NEW)",
            "code": "NEW"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

read http://json.org/

```
{
    "places": [
        {
            "name": "New\\x20Orleans,\\x20US\\x20\\x28New\\x20Lakefront\\x20\\x2D\\x20NEW\\x29",
            "code": "NEW"
        }
    ]
}
```